# How can I get the latest revision of CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: svn, git, cakephp, revision

This seems like a pretty beginner question; however, I have no idea what the link for the latest revision of cake 1.3 is. I have git and svn working with eclipse. I think cake is using git now instead of SVN (perhaps I am mistaken). If it is using git could someone give me some instruction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, CakePHP has moved to Git and Github:

```
git clone git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp1x.git
```

Will "checkout" the latest commit.

```
git pull
```

Will then "update" the repository to the HEAD revision.

**EDIT:** I just realised that CakePHP has a separate 1.3 development branch. You'll have to:

```
git branch --track 1.3 origin/1.3
git checkout 1.3
```

And that will switch you to the 1.3 branch.

Comment: ahhh yea, i was wondering what was going on.

Comment: actually i have another issue maybe you can answer it, I am getting a fatal:Not a repository (or any of its parent directories): .git

Comment: You have to cd to the directory that git creates (cakephp1x in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The above response by Brian McKenna works, but as of 4/4/12 the first command he lists does not work. I tried for HOURS to figure it out... and the problem is the inclusion of the "1x" in the URL:

```
git clone git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp1x.git targetdir
```

Running this command would result in

```
git clone git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp1x.git targetdir
Cloning into targetdir...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Instead, I was able to successfully check out the initial copy and then follow steps 2 and 3 to pull the 1.3 version by starting off with:

```
git clone git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git targetdir
```

I hope someone else who is following the above solution finds this and does not get stuck like I did.

Comment: yea, 1.3 should be on the master branch now, which is why cakephp1x didn't work. That branch is probably gone. This question is fairly old. It was before 1.3 was officially posted on the website. 

Finally, we are now at cakephp 2.0 and at some point the master branch is going to become 2.0. At which point perhaps this post wont even matter, but if someone is trying to access 1.3 at that point still, then you should check cakephp's official github and get a list of branches then select the one that pertains to you.